# Is MAC address used in all technologies

Tags: network-programming

I know that MAC address is used for local routing and error free data transfer, but is it used regardless the transmission medium infrastructure? I know it is used for Ethernet, but is it used for fiber, copper...etc?

Also, do we use MAC address when routing traffic between two adjacent routers? If we do, does that mean we have MAC address over serial connections?

Thanks

Comment: OSI is stone dead. Let it rest in peace. Mac addresses are for Ethernet. Off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAC addresses are used in most IEEE 802 network technologies, like Ethernet (802.3) and Wifi (802.11), but not all technologies use them. For instance, Fibre Channel use a different and more modern address type, called World Wide Name. It's longer and can be 64-bits or 128-bits.

So, to answer your questions, a router can use MAC addresses if it forwards packets over Ethernet interfaces, regardless of the physical medium. But it could also use other technologies or even label-switching protocols like MPLS. A serial link does not have medium access control and therefore has no MAC layer.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I was confused about the router part, since it was saying that when sending packets from one router to another, it uses the destination router MAC address

Answer (score 0):

> is it used regardless the transmission medium infrastructure? I know it is used for Ethernet, but is it used for fiber, copper...etc?

You mix OSI layer 1 (transmission medium) and layer 2 (Ethernet). If we use Ethernet as our data link layer, Ethernet MAC addresses will be there regardless of transmission medium. More on that on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

> do we use MAC address when routing traffic between two adjacent routers?

Yes, if the router are connected using Ethernet. Even if we use a back-to-back cable to connect two routers.

> does that mean we have MAC address over serial connections?

For the most of serial connections we do not use Ethernet, but use other layer 2 protocols, like ppp, Frame-Relay or HDLC. Note, that all of those protocols use their own addressing, but it is just one or two bytes, not 6 as in the Ethernet MACs. More on those protocols on Wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_Relay

Comment: Thanks Andriy. So what are the mediums for the Ethernet? May we use radio connection for Ethernet?

Comment: Sure, Ethernet works over a variety of copper (UTP, STP), optical (multi-
 and single-mode fibers), and wireless (2,4GHz or 5GHz) mediums. But the vice versa is not true, i.e. a variety of layer 2 protocols could be used over an optical fiber.

Comment: Thanks mate. So we do people use ppp between two routers although they can use Ethernet then?